# $scope.$on Called several times

Tags: angularjs

I am using

`$rootScope.$broadcast("closeviewMultiUserMainDetail");`

and using in by below

```
$rootScope.$on("closeviewMultiUserMainDetail", function (event) {
            //other code
        });
```

sometimes ‍‍`$rootScope.$on` Called several times.

How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$rootScope event listeners are not destroyed automatically and are always listening. That is why $rootScope.$on is getting called several times. You need to destroy the event listener using $destroy.

You can define your event like this:

> var closeviewMultiUserMainDetail = $rootScope.$on('closeviewMultiUserMainDetail', function(event) { });

You can then destroy it like this:

> $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
>           closeviewMultiUserMainDetail();   });

Comment: thank you.I acted on what you said, but it doesn't call $destroy.I made one console.log.but not in console browser.

Comment: new results.i am destroy with out $ and working correctly.thank you.  $scope.$on('destroy', function () {closeviewMultiUserMainDetail(); });